# Naming conventions and organization of packages

Tags: naming, organization, packages

I've been programming in Java, C#, Python and AS3 most of the time and in all of these languages there are *packages* (or something like that). The problem I found is with the naming convention, or even with the organization of the packages. I need someone to tell me WHY is this:

`com.company.app.type.Object` or `org.authorname.project.type.Object`

better than this:

`app.feature.Object` or `app.module.Object`

---

Another example:

Why this:

```
com
 +--company
     +--app
         +--events
         |   |--FeatureOneEventA
         |   |--FeatureOneEventB
         |   |--FeatureOneEventC
         |   |--FeatureTwoEventA
         |   |--FeatureTwoEventB
         |   
         +--models
         |   |--FeatureOne
         |   |--FeatureTwo
         |   
         +--services
             |--FeatureOneServiceA
             |--FeatureTwoServiceA
             |--FeatureTwoServiceB
```

Is "better" than this:

```
 company
  +--app
      +--feature
          +--one
          |   |--Model
          |   |
          |   +--events
          |   |   |--EventA
          |   |   |--EventB
          |   |   |--EventC
          |   |
          |   +--services
          |       |--ServiceA
          |  
          +--two
              |--Model
              |
              +--events
              |   |--EventA
              |   |--EventB
              |
              +--services
                  |--ServiceA
                  |--ServiceB
```

In the first one you have all organized by "types of objects", but the "features" are all mixed, but in the second one, the organization is by "feature" and each one has their own objects; so, you can see one feature well separated from another.

So, can anyone tell me why a lot of companies and programmers prefer the first?

Comment: There is a doubt that it may not be good to duplicate word `event` in package name and in class name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason to have your reverse domain name as the beginning of a package name is to reduce the possibility of naming conflicts. This is *especially* important if you are writing a library or a framework. So that explains why "com" and "org" are in there.

Other then that, everyone is different and chooses their package structure differently. One reason option 1 might be better is if there is no *real* destinction between features or they have a lot of code that crosses over. With that, option 2 might make more sense if features really are mutually exclusive in some manner.

Also, I bet option 1 is generally the way most projects start, and then nobody ever changes it (or cares to) after. I wouldn't be surprised if a lot of companys don't put a lot of thought into their package structure anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen, the first is common in Java and its kin (ActionScript, for example).  I don't quite know the reason why but I assume it's something to do with avoiding any possible naming clashes.

C# and .NET in general, as well as I believe Python, prefer the second style.  In fact, .NET guidelines expressly discourage the Java style and recommend: `CompanyName.ApplicationName.ModuleName.LogicalGroup` for example `Cyberdyne.Skynet.SelfDefense.CyborgActivation`

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the others on the package prefix being the company domain.

---

On the second point, I usually choose package names like you suggest, by feature before by file type (as you wrote, the other policy is often chosen).

Note that technical code (like StringHelper or MenuInterceptor) is not directly a feature, so it doesn't follow the same conventions.

I prefer it because :

- when working on a feature, you find easily the corresponding code
- you can make use of the `package` visibility (intermediate between a private inner class and a really public class).
- you can launch automatic tests to fully verify a feature (it is what matters to your client ; and it is also what could break when you modify old code)
- if a project typically have small features with few classes, or many optional classes that are not always needed, subdirectories might not be needed, all classes can be contained in the same package (and let the suffix indicated what role that class plays in the feature).

By the way, I think that several features don't usually share a lot of code. If a code is reusable, it is either:

- in a different layer (like technical code), so completely elsewhere (maybe not in the same Java project)
- in a superclass (common code may use packages as features do)

Answer (score 0):

Well the first is by pure convention. In the Java spec, packages are recommended to be named as the reverse of your company's domain name since that would ensure uniqueness. That's the reason Java packages are named that way.  C++ and C#, and therefore .NET, follow the namespace convention which has been around for years. I don't think any of these ways are inherently better than any other way, that is just the way the languages evolved.

Comment: And why people can't use "JAVA" instead of "Java" ???